# Alpha sort according to a specific part of string

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have a list of filenames, each file looking like this:

`https://www.dropbox.com/s/xxx/NF%208700%test%test%file.pdf?raw=1`

These files are dynamically put into a list, so they don't remain in their correct order. I'd like to sort the whole list at once, but only by the end of the url (the file name).

Like this:

`/NF%208700%test%test%file.pdf?raw=1`

I can get the end of the file by doing this

```
let index = curr.lastIndexOf("/");
console.log(curr.slice(index));
```

But my question is, how can I sort a whole list by only a specific part of a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solution

```
const data = ['https://www.dropbox.com/s/xxx/NF%2', 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/xxx/NF%1'];
const result = data.sort((nameA, nameB) => nameA.split('/').slice(-1)[0].localeCompare(nameB.split('/').slice(-1)[0]));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Giving me an error, `TypeError: a.split(...).slice(...)[0].localCompare is not a function`

Comment: localeCompare... not localCompare @23K

Comment: ah, those typos will get ya :)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Something along the lines of:

```
const sortedFiles = files.sort((a, b) => {
  return a.slice(a.lastIndexOf('/')) > b.slice(b.lastIndexOf('/'))
})
```

Comment: (localeCompare is probably better than comparison operators as suggested by user874774)

Comment: 'a' > 'b'
false;
'æ' > 'b'
true